# how to get files from Oracle VirtualBox without running it

Tags: virtualbox, files, oracle, password-recovery

hope this message finds you well. I am currently experiencing difficulty accessing machine from Oracle VirtualBox that is running on my windows 10 because I have forgot the password. I'm

wondering if anybody knows if I can access them from the host or do I have to get the password, and if I can hack it maybe?

thanks for helping in advance

edit: I have found how to change it and now I'm in but how do i export files from it to the host

Comment: If it's the password you forgot, it might be the easiest way to just boot your virtual machine  from a live cd iso. There you should be able to access the virtual harddisk.

Comment: To export files to the host, either set up a shared folder in VB, or use any method you would use to move files between 2 computers: thumb drive, cloud folder, scp, etc.